# How to scale kafka message consumption when consumers create bottleneck (high message processing time)?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, scaling

We have a kafka sdk written over apache-kafka (2.7.0) that we use to produce and consume messages to kafka topics.

By default the configuration is like this -

- Auto commit is set to false
- We use commitSync() for offsets
- poll frequency for consumers is 1000 ms
- max.poll.records is set to 2
- Consumers are single threaded and single consumer runs per instance/pod (we use EKS)

Now, there is a `order service` that produces `order-created` message to order topic and it is consumed by another service that fulfils the order `fulfil service`. The fulfilment logic takes on an average 20s to process this message (too high!).

Because of this even if we have 10 partitions in the topic and 10 application pods / consumers running (they all belong to same consumer group), we can only process 3 messages per minute per consumer (30 messages per minute overall).

The problem in rate of message production at peak is around 300 per minute. Even if we scale to 50 partitions with 50 consumers, we can only process 150 per minute. And even here, each consumer remains underutilized in terms of cpu and memory usage.

Because of this, over time, there is a huge build up in consumer lag.

How do we scale to solve this problem? We can't have 100s of underutilized consumers running as that is not cost effective. Please help with any pointers to solve this.

PS. : We are looking into how to optimize the consumer that is taking 20s on average, but it will take time and we need a short term solution for this that is cost effective as well.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to say it this way - but are you sure that Kafka is right tool for your job? Generally it's applied in architectures where the scale is way bigger than 300 per minute. In this cases Kafka is cost effective. 
Maybe some simpler choices like SQS/RabbitMQ/NSQ is the right tool? They will also hold 10x of your current scale.

Comment: I understand. And yes, with kafka, we can handle billions of messages in a day. We were using Amazon SNS before for this. We are migrating this to kafka as part of a bigger initiative. The problem is, using kafka, I am at a place where we cant handle even 300 per minute and I really want to understand how kafka can be scaled for such usecases.

Comment: Why are you only polling 2 records, and waiting up to 1 second for only those 2? The default poll amount is 500 records. Also, do you really need 10 pods vs multi-thread your consumers? e.g. 2 consumers in 5 pods, or 5 threads and 2 pods - that'll address your utilization issues

Comment: The problem with polling more records is that max.poll.interval.ms has a default value of 5 minutes. If a consumer polls 100 records, it will take 20*100 s (~33 mins) to process them before which the group will rebalance. Hence kept the poll size less.

Even if we run multiple consumers in a pod, it will solve utilization issue, but it wont solve for the consumer lag that keeps building.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather suggest "semi-lambda" architecture approach. If you are already running on k8s, use openfaas/knative to decouple handling of these messages:

1. First service that consumes messages, verifies them and spins up lambdas to handle those.
2. Actually lambdas, managed by openfaas or etc, this is classic use case when handling of message is higher than 500ms and not more than couple minutes. When this lambda finishes handling it will return response to first service. If it's okay - commit the offset, if not - also commit, but re-send to the dead queue.

Comment: Ok. When the service spins up lambda to handle the message, I assume, the service thread is not waiting for response. Once lambda is done, does it send the response through another callback? How does offset commit happen then?

Comment: it depends on a chosen framework to run lambdas. You can either check for exit code, for example this tutorial from openfaas: https://www.openfaas.com/blog/limits-and-backpressure/

Comment: Doesn't Knative eventing already integrate with Kafka?

Comment: @OneCricketeer and openfaas can integrate with Kafka too. It's not always the best idea to enable it, if it's a business critical and complex logic.